# why is there a different login-greeter when using ubuntu mate OEM-setup?

Tags: 17.10, login-screen, mate

When installing ubuntu mate 17.10 using oem-option I end up with a different login-greeter than when using the standard installation procedure. The "oem-greeter" is more like (or the very same) as in unity7.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 uses `gdm` (gnome display manager), where as the prior default for Ubuntu 11.10-17.04 was `lightdm`.  It is the display-manager that puts up the 'login-greeter' (generally). I've never seen the OEM version so this is conjecture only